# how to calculate Sharpe ratio from accumulate gain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, quantitative-finance

I have a lots of strategy and i am trying to calculate share ratio from accumulate gain.  For example, I have one -strategy accumulate gain vs time plot:
[image]

Here x axis is time where y axis is the accumulate gain in percentage. I can not figure it out how to calculate the sharpe ratio.

I am implementing the best stategy using genetic algorithm in python and in fitness function, I want to use sharpe ratio. But I am confuse how to calculate sharpe ratio from accumulate gain.

Can anyone suggest me how to do?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any modules with a built-in Sharpe Ratio function, but I did find [this code online](http://www.turingfinance.com/computational-investing-with-python-week-one/) which uses a user-written function to calculate the Sharpe Ratio.